# How to reference a style by key in PresentationFramework.Aero

Tags: wpf

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

In PresentationFramework.Aero.NormalColor.xaml has a style keyed NavigationWindowForwardButtonStyle

I try to apply the NavigationWindowForwardButtonStyle style to my button as below but it error

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NavigationWindowForwardButtonStyle}" Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Is it possible to set my button to the style keyed NavigationWindowForwardButtonStyle

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DynamicResource instead of StaticResorce.